# How to get 0 as a Count-output?

Tags: sql, database, count

```
SELECT Country.NAME, COUNT(City.NAME) as Number_of_cities
FROM City
JOIN Country ON City.COUNTRY = Country.CODE
WHERE City.LONGITUDE IS NULL AND City.LATITUDE IS NULL
GROUP BY Country.NAME, City.COUNTRY;
```

As the code is now, countries which only got cities with a longtidude and latitade value arent shown. How do i have to change the code, so that countries where all cities have longtitude and latidude values show 0 as coun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `left join`, with the filtering in the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT co.NAME, COUNT(ci.country) as Number_of_cities
FROM country co left join
     City ci
     ON ci.COUNTRY = co.CODE and
        ci.LONGITUDE IS NULL and
        ci.LATITUDE IS NULL
GROUP BY co.NAME;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.